# Custom Font on UIWebView only changes number's font

Tags: html, ios, css, fonts, uiwebview

I have added a custom font in app-info.plist and it just works on labels and buttons etc but nothing changes in uiwebview in which i show a html webpage. After almost trying almost every html and css code tricks which none of them worked out, i'm totally frustrated about it. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code :

```
 NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"something.com"]; [webDetailView loadHTMLString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"<style type='text/css'></style><meta name='viewport' content='img.content.x700 {width:auto;max-width:678px;}'/><body><div style='direction:rtl;'>%@</div></body>",detailObject.body] baseURL:targetURL];
```

which i changed them to :

```
NSURL *targetURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];
    NSString *htmlString =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"<html>"
                       "<style type=\"text/css\">"
                       "body { font-family:B Yekan;}"
                       "</style>"
                       "<head> </head>"
                       "<body>""<div style='direction:rtl;'>""%@""</div>"
                       "</body>"
                       "</html>",detailObject.body];
[webDetailView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:targetURL];
```

but nothing has changed

Comment: are you loading your html/css locally inside the project?

Comment: no I'm loading it from an online server.

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of your code? without this we can't help! There could be a number of reasons for example:  1. CSS @font-face not implemented correctly, see [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) for solution which works with all browsers. 2. font file not compatible for example ttf or otf, use a converter like this [website](http://convertfonts.com) 3. does the font work for any other browsers like Chrome?

Comment: I also have tried font face , several times, but still just the NUMBERS get affected.the font is ok and works on all browsers, its a ttf file and i'm using it on most of my labels which works, but when i wanna use it in uiwebview, just numbers get affected by the font, not the words.

Answer (score 0):

Save your font file inside the `Supporting Files` folder (it needs to be copied into the application bundle), then set the `font-family` of your text as the full name of the font. For example:

I have this font added to my `Supporting Files` folder:

[image: Font Info]

Notice the `Full Name` of the font.

Then create a `NSString` like this, which will use the custom font in the `body` of the `html`:

```
NSString *htmlString = 
@"<html>"
    "<style type=\"text/css\">"
       "body { font-family:Franklin Gothic Medium Cond;}"
    "</style>"
    "<head> </head>"
    "<body>"
       "Your text here"
    "</body>"
 "</html>";
```

Last, load the `htmlString` into the `UIWebView`, using the `bundleURL` as `baseURL` (this will make the `UIWebView` look for the font inside the application bundle):

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:url];
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but it didnt work, here is my code, 
     NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://something.com"];
    
[webDetailView loadHTMLString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"<style type='text/css'></style><meta name='viewport' content='img.content.x700 {width:auto;max-width:678px;}'/><body><div style='direction:rtl;'>%@</div></body>",detailObject.body] baseURL:targetURL];

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention one detail. The baseURL should be [NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL] in order to use any file that is inside the application bundle. I'll complete my answer.

Comment: Are you sure the font is being copied into the application bundle? In order to check that run the app on the iPhone Simulator, go to the iPhone Simulator Applications folder (~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[iOS Version Number]/Applications), find your application ".app" and right click > Show Package Contents. If the font file is not there, than that is the problem.